# Joomla SEF url: all pages point to default page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-sef-urls

I've set up a joomla webpage which is currently being hosted at a temporary url. When I enable the SEF url's all links point to the default/home page. 
Haven't found forum with this problem/solution.
please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled both htaccess and mod-rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Joomla 1.5, go to Site -> Global Configuration and turn on the 3 options that you have on the right side :

Search Engine Friendly URLs - YES

Use Apache mod_rewrite - YES

Add suffix to URLs - YES

Then rename htaccess.txt that you have in your joomla folder to .htaccess

You should have mod_rewrite on your Apache server to get that working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
After doing a little more research I found out that the server I'm using is not an apache server :( 
Meaning that this won't work

Any ideas?